# Get most recent responses from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have a dataset that I need to loop that returns a dataframe with only the most recent responses from each respondent, but I can't solve it, can you help me? The dataset is like this:

```
respondent         date         answer  
     1          22/08/2021         1
     1          23/08/2021         3
     1          25/08/2021         1
     2          22/08/2021         2
     2          22/08/2021         3
     2          23/08/2021         1
     3          22/08/2021         2
     3          24/08/2021         3
     4          22/08/2021         2
     4          25/08/2021         3
```

Comment: Post your code on what you have tried thusfar. This improves question quality, motivates others to help you faster and prevents reinventing the wheel in a direction not favorable for you. End of Review.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "respondent": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4],
        "date": pd.date_range(start="1/1/2018", end="1/08/2018"),
        "answer": [2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1],
    }
)
```

which looks like:

```
   respondent       date  answer
0           1 2018-01-01       2
1           1 2018-01-02       3
2           1 2018-01-03       1
3           2 2018-01-04       1
4           2 2018-01-05       2
5           3 2018-01-06       2
6           4 2018-01-07       3
7           4 2018-01-08       1
```

What you need is to:

1. group by the respondent
2. get his most recent date (max date)
3. find the row of the original dataframe with the date of previous step

This can be done by:

```
df_new = df[df.groupby('respondent').date.transform('max') == df['date']]
```

and will result in:

```
   respondent       date  answer
2           1 2018-01-03       1
4           2 2018-01-05       2
5           3 2018-01-06       2
7           4 2018-01-08       1
```